# Protractor test failing with angular-growl-v2

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, end-to-end

I'm using [angular-growl-v2](https://github.com/JanStevens/angular-growl-2) notifications in my app.

They work ok, the problem comes on my protractor tests. I have to use a TTL (around 6 seconds) as it is a requirement. Then I have the following test:

```
it('should send a request and notify the user about the result',function(){
    detailPage.verifyEmailtButton.click().then(function(){
      var expectedDiv = element(by.css('.alert-success'));
      expect(expectedDiv).toBeDefined();
    });
  });
```

But it is always throwing an error:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector(".alert-success")

This does not happens when the TLL is -1.

Someone can help here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

angular-growl-2 uses `$timeout`, which doesn't play nicely with protractor: protractor waits for the timeout to end before it completes its sync with angular process.

So by the time it reaches your `expect` call, the timeout has elapsed and the alert is no longer there. Check out the **Waiting for page synchronization** section of this doc:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md

(This page relates to timeouts, which you don't appear to be experiencing, but since the default timeout is 11 seconds, it could well be that the entire process, including your 6 second TTL, takes place before a timeout happens)

There's a PR to angular-growl-v2 to use `$interval` instead of `$timeout`, but its currently waiting for tests:

https://github.com/JanStevens/angular-growl-2/pull/85

Answer (score 0):

[Explicitly wait for the alert to be present](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions.prototype.presenceOf) after clicking the button:

```
detailPage.verifyEmailtButton.click();

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

var expectedDiv = element(by.css('.alert-success'));
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(expectedDiv), 10000, "No alert present");
```

Comment: That solution didn't work either. 
The thing is that when the TTL has a value, protractor waits for the angular-growl message to dissapear. Then, when the expectation is made, there is no such div.

Comment: @Santi is this a public site you are testing? In other words, instead of making guesses, can I reproduce the problem myself?